# Unable to load mojo plugin, A required class is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

While running the MVN install for a module getting the below mentioned exception.
In repository am having surefire 2.7.1, surefire-api 2.7.1 and surefire-booter 2.7.1.

.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire\2.7.1

.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api2.7.1

.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-booter\2.7.1

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) on project RegistrationServices: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireExecutionParameters**

how to solve that issue? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you include your pom? The class `SurefireExecutionParameters` is contained within the artifact `org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common`. I guess this isn't on the classpath.

Comment: @DB5 That issue got solved. I deleted the surefire folder from repo and ran the application with -resolved artifacts, so it got downloaded from the maven repo. Thanks for your reply..